# get_template_part() does not work if you call it when you are in a subfolder

Tags: get-template-part

Say for example you have a directory like this:

```
theme
  - subfolder
    - template.php
content-job-listing.php
```

If I try and call get_template_part like so `get_template_part('content', 'job-listing')` from the file template.php (note this is just a generic name not that actual name I'm using) it returns NULL.

Similarly, if I use `get_template_part('../content', 'job-listing')` this also fails to return the template. However, the first one works fine if both are in the same directory.

get_template_part() does not work if you call it when you are in a subfolder of a t

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to use get\_template\_part() with folders?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84721/is-there-any-way-to-use-get-template-part-with-folders)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`get_template_part()` will work the same no matter where or how deep you are within your theme. It always includes relative to the theme (or child theme) root.

So if you call the following from anywhere:

```
get_template_part( 'content', 'job-listing' );
```

... it will try to load (in order):

1. `child-theme/content-job-listing.php`
2. `parent-theme/content-job-listing.php`
3. `child-theme/content.php`
4. `parent-theme/content.php`

To load parts that are in a subdirectory of your theme, just use the path in the first argument:

```
get_template_part( 'path/to/file', 'optional-slug' );
```

Comment: Right. This is great, the main problem is to find which one of those files is going to be used in such and such case. For example, the index will load the `content.php` even if you think it should be the excerpt version... So in some situation, it can be confusing.